# How would I make a ProtobufEnum attribute converter?

Tags: java, jpa, protocol-buffers

I am trying to find a common way to store the that are generated by protobuf to an Attribute Converter.

Here's what I started with

```
package com.devhaus.als.portfolio.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.google.protobuf.ProtocolMessageEnum;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Component
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class ProtobufEnumConverter implements AttributeConverter<ProtocolMessageEnum, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final ProtocolMessageEnum attribute) {

        // I would've prefered string, but it may be more difficult.
        return attribute.getDescriptorForType().getName() + "/" + attribute.getNumber();
    }

    @Override
    public ProtocolMessageEnum convertToEntityAttribute(final String dbData) {

        // HOW!?!
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: ProtocolMessageEnum is an interface. Which implementation do you want to return ?

Comment: exactly, I am not sure how to reverse it back to something that implements the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the implementation is an enum :

```
@Component
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class ProtobufEnumConverter implements AttributeConverter<ProtocolMessageEnum, String> {

    private final static String SEP = "/";

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final ProtocolMessageEnum attribute) {
        if(attribute == null) return null;
        if(attribute instanceof Enum) {
            Enum<?> e = (Enum<?>) attribute;
            return e.getClass().getName() + SEP + e.name();
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("not an enum");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ProtocolMessageEnum convertToEntityAttribute(final String dbData) {
        if(dbData == null) return null;
        String[] tab = dbData.split(SEP);
        try {
            Class<? extends Enum> clazz = (Class<? extends Enum>) Class.forName(tab[0]);
            Enum res = Enum.valueOf(clazz, tab[1]);
            return (ProtocolMessageEnum) res;
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh that's pretty cool, it does not even need to be limited to gRPC but can be applied to almost any enum type

Comment: it's main limitation is that the class names (including packages) would be the same across implementations but most microservice architectures would tie the database to the service so it's a non-issue.

Comment: a way of making it take less space would be to use the simple name and "hard code" the package into the class (since it's application specific anyway)

Another improvement could be using the numeric value rather than the text so that it is more resilient to proto changes to the enum name.

Comment: Of course you can store the ordinal value but if someone reorder the enum, you are dead.

Comment: if someone reorders the enum that would violate normal protobuf anyway.